# JavaCV does not open another JFrame while capturing video from camera

Tags: java, swing, opencv, javacv

I have the class PyRecognizer that extends a JFrame and have the method "captura()":

```
public void captura() throws FrameGrabber.Exception{
    int nAmostras = 25, amostras = 1;
    KeyEvent tecla = null;
    OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat convertMat = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat();
    camera = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);

    CascadeClassifier detectorFace = new opencv_objdetect.CascadeClassifier("/home/tallys/NetBeansProjects/PyRecognizer/src/utils/haarcascade-frontalface-alt.xml");

    camera.start();

    CanvasFrame cFrame = new CanvasFrame("Video",CanvasFrame.getDefaultGamma()/camera.getGamma());
    Frame frameCapturado = null;
    Mat imagemColorida = new Mat();
    while((frameCapturado=camera.grab())!=null){
        imagemColorida = convertMat.convert(frameCapturado);
        imagemCinza = new Mat();
        cvtColor(imagemColorida,imagemCinza,opencv_imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
        RectVector facesDetectadas = new RectVector();
        detectorFace.detectMultiScale(imagemCinza, facesDetectadas,1.1,1,0,new Size(100,100),new Size(500,500));
        for(int i=0;i<facesDetectadas.size();i++){
            dadosFace = facesDetectadas.get(0);
            rectangle(imagemColorida,dadosFace, new Scalar(0,0,255,0));
        }
        if(cFrame.isVisible())
            cFrame.showImage(frameCapturado);
    }
    cFrame.dispose();
    camera.stop();

}
```

This capture videos from webcam and detect faces. But I have another class named as "Painel" that has the main method and extends from PyRecognizer(owner of captura() method) the constructor calls methods of PyRecognize.class.

```
public Painel() throws FrameGrabber.Exception, InterruptedException {
    initComponents();
    captura();
}
```

But when I run the app the only frame that open is the canvas of capture class and my JFrame named Painel does not open. I think that the problem is the while loop getting images from camera.

I've tried threads and sleep the code to wait the screen open first after the canvas of captura() method.

Comment: Can you please also share the code that instantiates your Painel/PyRecognizer class?

Comment: Yeah! The two classes are here

Painel.java
https://pastebin.com/VGzsT8H0

PyRecognizer.java
https://pastebin.com/8Ww0G65Y